# How to prove this function is quasi-convex/concave?

Tags: convex-optimization

this is the function:

$$\displaystyle f(a,b) = \frac{b^2}{4(1+a)}$$

Comment: http://www.hecer.fi/FDPE/documents/mathcamp/2011/Handouts/concavity.pdf

Comment: http://www.rmi.ge/~kade/LecturesT.Kadeishvili/MathEconomics/Term4/Week6Concave.pdf

Answer (score 2):

For quasi convexity you have to consider for $\alpha\in R$ the set
$$\{(a,b)\in R^{2}: f(a,b)\leq \alpha\}
$$
If this set is convex for every $\alpha \in R$ you have quasi convexity.

So we obtain the equality
$$4(1+a)\leq \alpha b^{2}.$$

If you draw this set as set in $R^{2}$ for fixed $\alpha\in R$, this should give you a clue about quasi convexity...